# Blackberry phone listener not working

Tags: blackberry, java-me, listener

When I use the simulator, everything works fine. However, when I debug on a real phone, the phone listener doesn't catch anything; such as when a call is answered, connected etc.

Any ideas about what can be going wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

The simulator ignores permissions and signing keys. Make sure your app is [signed](https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/) and requesting the right permissions when used on a real device. For the Phone listener, you would need the [Phone permission](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/applicationcontrol/ApplicationPermissions.html#PERMISSION_PHONE).